# XPath Finding Nodes By Count

Tags: xpath

Find the h1s for every div with three list elements in it. ([source](http://practicalsqa.net/advanced-brainteaser-finding-by-count/))

```
<div>
    <div class="fast">
      <h1>Fast</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Cars</li>
        <li>New Horizon</li>
        <li>Chinese Food</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="expensive">
      <h1>Expensive</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Cars</li>
        <li>New Horizon</li>
        <li>Apple Watches</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="nasa">
      <h1>NASA-Owned</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Lunar Module</li>
        <li>New Horizon</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This worked for me, (but I wish to find simpler syntax)

```
//ul/li[count(../li)=3]/../../h1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write

```
//div[count(.//li)=3]/h1
```

But be careful: you asked for "every div with three list elements in it" which this gives you; the accepted answer gives you "every element containing at least one unnumbered list that has exactly three list items in it", which is not the same thing, although it might give the same result on this particular test document.

Comment: Thank you very much for you  precise note.

Comment: still not OK from the logical point of view. That `div` could be placed much above `ul` element, and it will be selected if it has `h1` in it. It could not even have ul element) 
I mean for study purposes it's ok to write such locator, but I won't recommend using this in project)

Comment: The only thing we know about the requirements is what's in the question. I agree that in a real project one would be looking for a more precise statement of requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Can't make it shorter/simpler =)

```
//div[ul[count(li)=3]]/h1
```

PS. ok this is final:

```
//*[ul[count(li)=3]]/h1
```

Comment: Excellent :), I think you should keep `div` as it is required, I know it will be correct in both cases but more accurate with `div` :)

Comment: yes, better to keep div=) and for maintainability even add classes/ids to be sure that it's proper element ) but it's the simplest configuration that anyone can adjust to his needs)

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement [following-sibling axis](http://www.way2tutorial.com/xml/xpath_node_test_examples.php#18) syntax as below:

```
//h1[following-sibling::ul[count(li)=3]]
```

Comment: Very useful link, Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

To match exact h1 under div:

```
//div/h1[following-sibling::ul[count(li)=3]]
```